# &str not converted into StyleSource implicitly in rust stylist

Tags: html, css, rust, rust-crates, yew

I am trying out yew and stylist for the first time in rust. As per the tutorials, i should be able to convert `&str` into the required type, but it produces the error given as:

```
the trait `From<&str>` is not implemented for `StyleSource`
```

The error is shown in the image for reference.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGdDh.png)

Following is my code.

```rust
use stylist::{yew::styled_component, Style};

#[styled_component(App)]
pub fn app() -> Html {    
    let style_str = "background-color: red;";
    let stylesheet = Style::new(style_str).unwrap();
    html! {
            <div class={stylesheet}>
                <h1>{"Hello World using stylesheet!"}</h1>
                <p>{"some more text..."}</p>
            </div>
    }
}
```

I was trying frontend development in RUST using online tutorials.
To do this I was using `yew` and `stylist` dependencies to work with html and css codes.
As per documentation, a parsed `css` file should be able to run using `Style::new(name_of_variable)`. But it is throwing the stated error.

Comment: Please post the full error from `cargo check` **as text**. See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: It says this on the [front page of stylist's documentation](https://docs.rs/stylist/latest/stylist/index.html#style-api): "If you want to parse a string into a style at runtime, you need to enable the parser feature."

Comment: Thanks for the image info. Will keep that in mind. @ChayimFriedman

Comment: Yes including "parser" feature along with stylist worked. Thanks a lot @drewtato

Comment: Cool, I've turned it into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[String conversions](https://docs.rs/stylist/latest/stylist/struct.StyleSource.html#impl-TryFrom%3C%26%27a+str%3E-for-StyleSource) are behind the `parser` cargo feature. You can enable this feature in Cargo.toml.

```ini
[dependencies]
stylist = { version = "0.12.1", features = ["parser"] }
```

Then, your code should work as-is.